# sed to copy part of line to end

Tags: sed, text-processing

I'm trying to copy part of a line to append to the end:

```
ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/900/169/985/GCA_900169985.1_IonXpress_024_genomic.fna.gz
```

becomes:

```
ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/900/169/985/GCA_900169985.1/GCA_900169985_IonXpress_024_genomic.fna.gz
```

I have tried:

```
sed 's/\(.*(GCA_\)\(.*\))/\1\2\2)'
```

Comment: A more simplified question would be "How to change `ftp://one/two/three_four/five` to `ftp://one/two/three_four/three/five`

Comment: I think it would be better if OP explains how the new version is arrived at... could be as simple as `xyz.5_foo.bar.baz` to `xyz.5/xyz_foo.bar.baz`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ f1=$'ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/900/169/985/GCA_900169985.1_IonXpress_024_genomic.fna.gz'

$ echo "$f1"
ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/900/169/985/GCA_900169985.1_IonXpress_024_genomic.fna.gz

$ sed -E 's/(.*)(GCA_.[^.]*)(.[^_]*)(.*)/\1\2\3\/\2\4/' <<<"$f1"
ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/900/169/985/GCA_900169985.1/GCA_900169985_IonXpress_024_genomic.fna.gz
```

sed -E (or -r in some systems) enables extended regex support in sed , so you don't need to escape the group parenthesis `( )`.

The format `(GCA_.[^.]*)` equals to "get from GCA_ all chars up and excluding the first found dot" :

```
$ sed -E 's/(.*)(GCA_.[^.]*)(.[^_]*)(.*)/\2/' <<<"$f1"
GCA_900169985
```

Similarly `(.[^_]*)` means get all chars up to first found `_` (excluding `_` char). This is the regex way to perform a non greedy/lazy capture (in perl regex this would have been written something like as `.*_?`)

```
$ sed -E 's/(.*)(GCA_.[^.]*)(.[^_]*)(.*)/\3/' <<<"$f1"
.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Short ***sed*** approach:

```
s="ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/900/169/985/GCA_900169985.1_IonXpress_024_genomic.fna.gz"
sed -E 's/(GCA_[^._]+)\.([^_]+)/\1.\2\/\1/' <<< "$s"
```

The output:

```
ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/900/169/985/GCA_900169985.1/GCA_900169985_IonXpress_024_genomic.fna.gz
```